# How to display an image from API and send the user to video link after clicking the image? Kotlin, Retrofit

Tags: android, image, kotlin, android-recyclerview, thumbnails

I am trying to display a video Thumbnail in recyclerview  with it is Title

here is my data class:

```
data class PropertyItem(
    val id: Int,
    val thumbnailUrl: String,
    val title: String,
    val videoId: String,
    val videoUrl: String
)
```

and here is the list_item xml:

```
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".3"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var manager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
    private lateinit var myAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        manager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        getAllData()
    }

    fun getAllData(){
        Api.retrofitService.getAllData().enqueue(object: Callback<List<PropertyItem>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<PropertyItem>>,
                response: Response<List<PropertyItem>>
            ) {
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view).apply{
                        myAdapter = MyAdapter(response.body()!!)
                        layoutManager = manager
                        adapter = myAdapter
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<PropertyItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                t.printStackTrace()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Adapter

```
class MyAdapter(private val data: List<PropertyItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>()  {

    class MyViewHolder(val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        fun bind(propertyItem: PropertyItem){
            val title = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvTitle)
            val imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageViewid)

            title.text = propertyItem.title
            Glide.with(view.context).load(propertyItem.thumbnailUrl).centerCrop().into(imageView)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(data[position])
    }
}
```

so I'm getting all the data from data class but it doesn't display the image and how to add url to the imageview so the user can click the image and redirected to the viedo?

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.codevscolor.com/android-kotlin-recyclerview-with-image

am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you post your recycler view adapter code?

Comment: @luca_999 I forgot to add it before, I just added it

Comment: what is the value of `propertyItem.thumbnailUrl`? Also, you need to set a click listener to handle clicks.

Comment: @RyanM its in data class "val thumbnailUrl: String"

Comment: Okay, so if that's only place it's used, then it would be null and that would be your problem.  If not, then we'd need the _value_ (not the declaration).

Comment: @RyanM lol, you didn't help at all, you didn't even try to guide me or explain anything to me, (straight away saying "that would be your problem"), I'm not expert and I asked here searching for help and answers and you provided none

Comment: I'm trying to help you.  You're not giving me the information I need to do so.  My guess is that there's something wrong with your `thumbnailUrl` value, but you've repeatedly refused to say what it is.  Thus, I cannot help you.

Comment: @RyanM I really don't understand what value do you need here, I attached the tutorial that I was following at the end of the question and I follow exactly the same steps there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code solved my problem

```
Picasso.with(activity)
            .load(countryList[position].thumbnailUrl)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE, NetworkPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(holder.thumbnailUrl)
```

I had to use Picasso not Glide